# ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden in youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to download Udemy site videos with youtube-dl.
This is a sample code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3G4K.png)

I also used the following command but the problem was not solved

```
youtube-dl --rm-cache-dir
```

I also use the latest version of youtube-dl.
Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26600

It's a known issue. There's no fix for it at this time. Udemy changed how their cookies and session-id's are handled.

Answer (score 0):

First, find the directory `which youtube-dl`
For me it was '/usr/bin/youtube-dl' in Ubuntu 20.04.
Then grant the permission `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/bin/youtube-dl`.
Then enter the command.
This worked for me though the download speed is really low.
Hope this will work for you as well.
** Try `--verbose` if the problem is still there.